# stop(getSelf()) vs stop(this.getSelf())

Tags: java, java-8, akka, actor

I have been studying Akka Actors. I know the meaning of stop(ActorRef) which kills the running actor. But what is the difference between getSelf() and this.getSelf() while killing an actor? Thank You in advance!.

Comment: `getSelf` is kind of a like a syntactic sugar for `this.getSelf`. Who wants to write `this.` for every instance method they call, anyway?

Comment: Question really has nothing to do with Akka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between them, it's just that some people believe it enhances readability.

*Readability* is an important thing in programming but in this specific case, I personally believe they are just as readable with or without the `this` prefix.